# What do these attributes refer to in the SEDE Schema?

Tags: support, data-explorer, schema

In the SEDE [Schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) under `Votes` -> `VoteTypeId`, there are

- `Upmod`
- `DownMod`
- `InformModerator` (Probably refers to the Inform Moderator Flag ?)
- `ModeratorReview`

What do each of these atttributes refer to ?

Comment: I think it's just the old names for upvote and downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are names for the following:

- `UpMod`: Upvote
- `DownMod`: Downvote
- `InformModerator`: Not actually used anywhere, not sure what this was intended for
- `ModeratorReview`: Inserted when a moderator views a flagged post